# Is there a way to insert chart in word through office.js

Tags: office-js

I’m working on a office.js add-in for word, it need a function as below:

1. retrive data from network
2. insert a chart and fill the chart with the data
3. in the future, the add-in can update the chart if the data has been updated

I can’t find how to do this in the API documents, does anybody know how to achieve this goal?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the OOXML content from the Excel file and try to insert it in to Word file for the selected object. For more information, You can refer link below.

[Create better add-ins for Word with Office Open XML](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md)

You can get an example from link below:

[fficeDev/Word-Add-in-Get-Set-EditOpen-XML](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Get-Set-EditOpen-XML)